# Error when uploading video to YouTube with cURL and API v3

Tags: ssl, curl, upload, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload video to YouTube with `cURL and API v3`. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message:

> *"curl: (1) SSL is disabled, https: not supported"*

What does it mean and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message "*curl: (1) SSL is disabled, https: not supported*" means that the instance of curl/libcurl that you're using was built without support for this protocol.

This could've happened if **the configure script that was run at build time couldn't find all libs and include files curl requires for SSL to work**. If the configure script fails to find them, curl is simply built without SSL support.

To get the https:// support into a curl that was previously built but that reports that https:// is not supported, you should dig through the logs and check out why the configure script doesn't find the SSL libs and/or include files. This may be because of several reasons, e.g. native linker doesn't find openssl or only the libssl lib is missing.

Try to re-compile cURL with SSL support (something like: ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl) to see if it helps to resolve the issue.

Reference: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#curl_1_SSL_is_disabled_https